# ImportError: No module named _____

Tags: python

There are many questions with slight variations of this problem in SO. None of the answers I've seen solve my problem, so I'm asking a new question.

I have this folder structure:

```
/myapp/
   \__init__.py
    modu1.py
    modu2.py
```

`__init__.py` *is empty*

**modu1.py**

```
class TestMod1Class():
    def msg(self):
        print "Hello World!"
```

**modu2.py**

```
import myapp.modu1 

obj = myapp.modu1.TestMod1Class()
obj.msg()
```

If from the directory /myapp/ I run `python modu2.py` i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modu2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myapp.modu1
ImportError: No module named myapp.modu1
```

What I'm I doing wrong? I've read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), and still can't make sense of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If from the directory /myapp/ I run `python modu2.py` i get

If you run a module directly, it does not run as part of a package it might belong to. As such importing `myapp.modu1` will look for `myapp/myapp/modu1.py`, which is obviously not where it is.

If you want the `myapp` package to work, you have to start the execution from within the root directory. So add a `main.py` next to the `myapp` folder:

```
/main.py
/myapp
    /__init__.py
    /modu1.py
    /modu2.py
```

And from there, you can do:

```
import myapp.modu2
```

And then you have to start with `python main.py`.

Answer (score 5):

You are already within the `myapp` module by being in the `myapp` folder. Therefore, you do not need to use the `import myapp.modu1` syntax and instead should use `import modu1`.

For example:

```
import modu1

obj = modu1.TestMod1Class()
obj.msg() # output: Hello World!
```

Note: I tested in Python 3 because I don't have 2 on my machine, but it should be the same (I did edit modu1 to use the new `print` syntax).

Comment: Relative imports are long deprecated; if they “work” at all in Python 3, it is only because they are (temporarily) available as **top-level** packages due to something like the current working directory being put on `sys.path`.